# How to keep prompting for input until it is valid?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make it so when the given answer is neither 1 nor 2 the message "Please enter a valid answer." shows up and it goes back to the question.

Here's my code:

```
Coloration(ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta, "What do you want to do? [1/2]");
Console.WriteLine("1. Draw");
Console.WriteLine("2. Stay");
int i = 0;
string input1 = Console.ReadLine();
// If answer is not 2, go through this, if answer is 2 continue
if (input1 != "2")
{
    // If answer is 1 add 1 to i
    if (input1 == "1")
    {
        i++;
    }

    // If answer is neither 1 nor 2; go back to question
    if (input1 != "1" || input1 != "2")
    {
        Coloration(ConsoleColor.Red, "Please enter a valid answer.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your flow control is missing up there's no logic in your if statements, in order words you can use the switch case statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have noted, you need to keep watching user input. You have your answer but I wanted to also introduce you to the concept of a Read Eval Print Loop (AKA a REPL). Your current solution is not going to scale well. Take a look at the following implementation of your desired UI:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        // Don't actually use inner classes. This is just for demonstration purposes.
        class Command
        {
            public Command(string description, Action action)
            {
                this.Description = description;
                this.Action = action;
            }
            public string Description { get; private set; }
            public Action Action { get; private set; }

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a dictionary of commands, mapped to the input that evokes each command.
            var availableCommands = new Dictionary<string, Command>();
            // Note that since we are storing the descriptions / commands in one place, it makes
            // changing a description or adding/modifying a command trivial. Want "Draw" to be invoked
            // by "d" instead of "1"? Change it here and you're done.
            availableCommands.Add("1", new Command("Draw", Draw));
            availableCommands.Add("2", new Command("Stay", Stay));
            // This command demonstrates how to use a lambda as an action if you so desire.
            availableCommands.Add("3", new Command("Exit", () => System.Environment.Exit(1)));

            // Build command list string
            var cmdList = string.Join('/', availableCommands.Keys);

            // Display welcome message
            Coloration(ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta, $"What do you want to do? [{cmdList}]");

            // Show user initial list of commands
            DisplayAvailableCommands(availableCommands);

            // Read Eval Print Loop (REPL).
            while (true)
            {
                var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
                // If the user entered a valid command, execute it.
                if (availableCommands.ContainsKey(userInput))
                {
                    availableCommands[userInput].Action();
                    // If you want the user to be able to perform additional actions after their initial successful
                    // action, don't return here.
                    return;
                }
                // Otherwise, let them know they didn't enter a valid command and show them a list of commands
                else
                {
                    Coloration(ConsoleColor.Red, "Please enter a valid answer.");
                    DisplayAvailableCommands(availableCommands);
                }
            }
        }

        // I'm just assuming your coloration method looks something like this...
        static void Coloration(ConsoleColor color, string message)
        {
            // Keep track of original color so we can set it again.
            var originalColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
            Console.ForegroundColor = color;
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            Console.ForegroundColor = originalColor;
        }

        static void DisplayAvailableCommands(Dictionary<string, Command> commands)
        {
            // We always want a line above the commands
            Console.WriteLine("Available commands:");
            foreach (string key in commands.Keys)
            {
                var command = commands[key];
                Console.WriteLine($"{key}. {command.Description}");
            }
        }

        static void Draw()
        {
            Coloration(ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, "You chose to draw!");
        }

        static void Stay()
        {
            Coloration(ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, "You chose to stay!");
        }
    }
}
```

Adding new commands will be a breeze. And you can further refactor this to even smaller single-purpose methods. Each command could have its' own class in the event that your commands become more complicated (and in a real app, they will. Trust me). You can refactor the REPL to its' own class/method as well (take a look at [this implementation I did a while back](https://github.com/DeanPDX/sql-fileizer/blob/master/InteractiveUserInterface.cs) for example).

Anyway, this is my $.02 on a more correct way you could build a user interface of this nature. Your current solution is going to work, but it's not going to be fun to work with long-term. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You want something more like this...

```
        Console.WriteLine("What do you want to do? [1/2]");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Draw");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Stay");

        int userChoice = 0;
        bool validInput = false;

        while (!validInput)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter choice [1/2]...");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            string trimmedInput = input.Trim();

            if (trimmedInput == "1" || trimmedInput == "2")
            {
                validInput = true;
                userChoice = Int32.Parse(trimmedInput);
            }
        }
        // We leave the while loop here once validInput == true
        // Now take action based on userChoice

        Console.WriteLine("You chose " + userChoice);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score -1):

use a while loop to continuously ask for input if not valid, then check the input with a switch statement

```
bool flag = false;
while(!flag)
{
    switch(input1)
    {
        case "1": 
            flag = true;
            break;
        case "2":
            flag = true;
            break;
        default:
            Coloration(ConsoleColor.Red, "Please enter a valid answer.");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will produce an infinite loop when invalid input is provided. Also, better use a more descriptive variable name than `flag`.